# Synchronization of Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I want to synchronize the tasks when one task is completed only when its callback is received.

Let me explain my scenario.

In a function, I am having multiple tasks and each succeeding task will only run after the successfully completion of the preceding task. This can be achieve using  `ContinueWith` & `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`. I just want to know that how can I synchronize two or more tasks when the result of one task will come in a callback and that callback is a general callback. I cannot create my succeeding task in the callback.

```
int SomeFunction()
{
  Task<FirstTaskReturn> FirstTask = new Task<FirstTaskReturn>(() => FirstTaskFunction)
  FirstTask.Start();

  Task<SecondTaskReturn> SecondTask = FirstTask.ContinueWith(task => SecondTaskFunction(FirstTask.Result),TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
  Task<ThirdTaskResult> ThirdTask = SecondTask.ContinueWith(task => ThirdTaskFunction(SecondTask.Result),TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
  Task FourthTask = ThirdTask.ContinueWith(task => FourthTaskFunction(ThirdTask.Result),TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}

ThirdTaskResult ThirdTaskFunction(SecondTaskResult x)
{
   //Here I am firing some commands to a ZWave device one by one in loop
}

void callback(byte response)
{
   switch(response)
   {
       case 1:
           //do some work for case 1
           break;
       case 2:
          //do some work for case 2
          break;
       case 3:
          //do some work for case 3
          break;
       case 4:
          //do some work for case 4
          break;
       case 5:
          //do some work for case 5
          break;
}
```

Now I am firing some commands to a ZWDevice one by one in a loop in `ThirdTaskFunction`. Responses of these commands will be returned in a callback (whose definition is not in my control, as it is defined by some third party framework). In the callback I am checking the byte value for which command this response came and work accordingly. This means that if in `ThirdTaskFunction` I am firing 3 commands then I will get 3 callbacks in `callback`.
Now I only want to run the FourthTask when all callbacks are received. But I found that my FourthTask is executing before my all callbacks are received.

So I want to synchronize this. I cannot run my FourthTask in the `callback` itself as it is a general callback which will be called in some other scenario also i.e. when I will give some command to ZWdevice on user action.

Is there any way of achieving this??
Hope now I am clear to you.

Comment: Does `ThirdTaskFunction()` return before "all the callbacks are received"? If not, what's wrong with what you have, i.e. `ThirdTask.ContinueWith(...)`? If it does return, then are you just looking for `TaskCompletionSource`? I.e. rather than wrapping the call to `ThirdTaskFunction()` in a `Task`, call the function directly, and have the callback-handling code call `SetResult()` on the `TaskCompletionSource` once you are ready for the fourth task to run.

Comment: Your question is not very clear; if neither of those seem right, please clarify the question. Provide a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates what you mean, and describe precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: it seems the 4th task should after from callback... what is the constraint ?

Comment: Hi Peter, I have edited my question and tried to make you understand my case. Yes my `ThirdTaskFunction()` returns before "all callbacks are received"

Comment: Umm...isn't this like why Microsoft created the `Task` object along with `async` and `await`?

Answer (score 1):

```
async Task<int> SomeFunction()
{
    var result1 = await FirstTaskFunction();
    var result2 = await SecondTaskFunction(result1);
    var result3 = await ThirdTask(result2);
    ...ad nausum..
}

async Task<> ThirdTaskFunction(SecondTaskResult x)
{
    foreach(var device in devices)
    {
       await DoStuffToZWave(device);
    }
}

public Task<T> DoStuffToZWave(device) //NOTICE LACK OF ASYNC
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>()
    //Do stuff
    foo.callback += (o, e) => tcs.SetResult(theResult);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272)